# How do I figure out why MySQL isn't letting me query a view?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySql 5.6.  I'm querying a view and getting this error

```
mysql> select * FROM report_toc_item;
ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'my_db.report_toc_item' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
mysql>
```

I can see the view definition and there doesn't look like there's anything wrong

```
mysql>  SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE table_schema = 'my_db' and TABLE_NAME = 'report_toc_item';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| VIEW_DEFINITION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| select `ti`.`ID` AS `ID`,`ti`.`PARENT_ID` AS `PARENT_ID`,`ti`.`TOC_ID` AS `TOC_ID`,`ti`.`TITLE` AS `TITLE`,`ti`.`DESCRIPTION` AS `DESCRIPTION`,`ti`.`TYPE_ID` AS `TYPE_ID`,`ti`.`ORDER_NUM` AS `ORDER_NUM`,`ti`.`MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ID` AS `MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ID`,`ti`.`MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ORDER_NUM` AS `MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ORDER_NUM`,`ti`.`ELEMENT_ID` AS `ELEMENT_ID`,`ti`.`UNIT_TOC_ITEM_ID` AS `UNIT_TOC_ITEM_ID`,`ti`.`SHORT_NAME` AS `SHORT_NAME`,`ti`.`THIRD_PARTY_PROMPT_ID` AS `THIRD_PARTY_PROMPT_ID`,`pti`.`TYPE_ID` AS `PARENT_TYPE_ID` from (`my_db`.`toc_item` `ti` join `my_db`.`toc_item` `pti` on((`pti`.`ID` = `ti`.`PARENT_ID`))) where ((`ti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'sub_segment') and ((`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'lesson') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'activity') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'activity_practice') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'unit_opener'))) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

How do I figure out what columns and tables are invalid?  Note that I'm logged in as root when running both commands.

**Edit:** Here is the result of "SHOW CREATE VIEW report_toc_item," as requested.

```
mysql> show create view report_toc_item;
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| View               | Create View                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | character_set_client | collation_connection |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| report_toc_item | CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`myuser`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `report_toc_item` AS select `ti`.`ID` AS `ID`,`ti`.`PARENT_ID` AS `PARENT_ID`,`ti`.`TOC_ID` AS `TOC_ID`,`ti`.`TITLE` AS `TITLE`,`ti`.`DESCRIPTION` AS `DESCRIPTION`,`ti`.`TYPE_ID` AS `TYPE_ID`,`ti`.`ORDER_NUM` AS `ORDER_NUM`,`ti`.`MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ID` AS `MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ID`,`ti`.`MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ORDER_NUM` AS `MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ORDER_NUM`,`ti`.`ELEMENT_ID` AS `ELEMENT_ID`,`ti`.`UNIT_TOC_ITEM_ID` AS `UNIT_TOC_ITEM_ID`,`ti`.`SHORT_NAME` AS `SHORT_NAME`,`ti`.`THIRD_PARTY_PROMPT_ID` AS `THIRD_PARTY_PROMPT_ID`,`pti`.`TYPE_ID` AS `PARENT_TYPE_ID` from (`toc_item` `ti` join `toc_item` `pti` on((`pti`.`ID` = `ti`.`PARENT_ID`))) where ((`ti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'sub_segment') and ((`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'lesson') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'activity') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'activity_practice') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'unit_opener'))) | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

**Edit 2:**

Here are the grants assigned for the user in question

```
mysql> show grants for 'myuser'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myuser@localhost                |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Run the select that's generating the view, you'll get a more meaningful error message from there

Comment: When I run the SELECT statement all by itself that the view represents, everything runs fine.  Wtf??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full error message is:

```
... or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

Check the view definer, and if there is one, check that *the definer account* can execute the select.

To see the definer, use:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW

SELECT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE ...
```

Comment: I edited my question to include the "SHOW CREATE VIEW".  What do I need to substitute for teh "..." that you have above after "WHERE"?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.Views WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'report_toc_item'\G`

Comment: @Dave, Thanks for the update. So, in this case, make sure that `myuser`@`localhost` has privileges to select from the tables.

Comment: Hi, Good deal.  I included the output for "show grants for 'myuser'@'localhost'" in my question as a further edit.  Let me know what additional rights I might need to add to the user.

Comment: @Dave, your original question is answered then: the view does not work, because it uses a definer that has no SELECT privileges for the table. Before adding privileges, you should really ask yourself why a definer was used when creating the view, and/or if this user really should see the tables or not. Privileges are for security: do not just open them "to make it work" without considering implications.

Comment: Ok, so you're sayhing that adding SELECT privileges will solve the problem?  If so can you include what the SQL I need to run and who should run it?  You can add a note about why it is dangerous and other caveats.  I accept the fact that if it lets Russian hackers take down my site, it is my own fault.

Comment: The SQL syntax is GRANT SELECT ON my_db.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'; run it from an account that can grant privileges (like root). See the doc at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html

Comment: @Marc Alff, you should add the GRANT script in your answer so that it is clear for others seeking the same solution. Additionally, here is what "USAGE" privilege means: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage

Answer (score 3):

`DEFINER=myuser@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER` means that the view will be executed with the rights of `myuser@localhost` (not as your current root login), see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-security.html):

> - A stored program or view that executes in definer security context executes with the privileges of the account named by its DEFINER attribute. These privileges may be entirely different from those of the invoking user. The invoker must have appropriate privileges to reference the object (for example, EXECUTE to call a stored procedure or SELECT to select from a view), but when the object executes, the invoker's privileges are ignored and only the DEFINER account privileges matter. If this account has few privileges, the object is correspondingly limited in the operations it can perform. If the DEFINER account is highly privileged (such as a root account), the object can perform powerful operations no matter who invokes it.
> - A stored routine or view that executes in invoker security context can perform only operations for which the invoker has privileges. The DEFINER attribute can be specified but has no effect for objects that execute in invoker context.

So depending on what you want to achieve, either grant the required rights to `myuser@localhost`, change the `definer` to a user that has these rights or change the `sql security` to `invoker`. Usually, the second option will be used, unless you have reasons not to.

To change the `definer` or the `sql security`, you will have to `alter` (or drop and recreate) the view, including the whole `as select ...` part. You can use the output of `show create view report_toc_item` for that and just change it at the beginning. The default values for `definer` and `sql security` will be the current user and `definer`.

Comment: You're dealing with a novice here -- I'm not understanding what SQL statements I need to run to fix the issue.  As a further edit to my question, I included the GRANTS that the user has.  Let me know i they need additional privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, only changed definer to invoker and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

> If a view references an invalid column, then show create view won't work.

So check the following query that define the view work properly. Because if you delete any column from `toc_item` table then the view will not work.

`` select `ti`.`ID` AS `ID`,`ti`.`PARENT_ID` AS `PARENT_ID`,`ti`.`TOC_ID` AS TOC_ID\,`ti`.`TITLE` AS `TITLE`,`ti`.`DESCRIPTION` AS `DESCRIPTION`,`ti`.`TYPE_ID` AS `TYPE_ID`,`ti`.`ORDER_NUM` AS `ORDER_NUM`,`ti`.`MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ID` AS `MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ID`,`ti`.`MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ORDER_NUM` AS `MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ORDER_NUM`, `ti`.`ELEMENT_ID` AS `ELEMENT_ID`, `ti`.`UNIT_TOC_ITEM_ID` AS `UNIT_TOC_ITEM_ID`,`ti`.`SHORT_NAME` AS `SHORT_NAME`,`ti`.`THIRD_PARTY_PROMPT_ID` AS `THIRD_PARTY_PROMPT_ID`, `pti`.`TYPE_ID` AS `PARENT_TYPE_ID` from (`my_db`.`toc_item` `ti` join `my_db`.`toc_item` `pti` on((`pti`.`ID` = `ti`.`PARENT_ID`))) where ((`ti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'sub_segment') and ((`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'lesson') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'activity') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'activity_practice') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'unit_opener'))); ``

## See the following example:

```
 create table test
 (
    x integer not null,
    y integer not null
 );

 create or replace view test_view as select * from test;

 alter table test drop column y;
```

## As expected, this won't work.

```
 select * from test_view;
```

## But this won't work either.

```
 show create view test_view;

 drop table test;
```

## As expected, this still won't work.

```
 select * from test_view;
```

## But bizarrely, this now does work!

```
 show create view test_view;
```

Source [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76484)

Answer (score 0):

Login as **myuser** not as **root** because the definer is **myuser**.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you authenticate with MySQL from localhost as myuser.  Ensure you've flushed the privileges before running any tests.

From the MySQL Manual: "To tell the server to reload the grant tables, perform a flush-privileges operation. This can be done by issuing a FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement or by executing a mysqladmin flush-privileges or mysqladmin reload command."

Instead of granting USAGE, grant ALL and remove "ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`myuser`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER".

Put a conditional DROP TABLE IF EXISTS in the top of an exhaustive experimental file (that aggregates all the set up and the test)

Run the test and get it to work in the simplest of cases and then incrementally add in the restrictions and features to the table to find the breaking point.  Get everything else to work but the feature that breaks the access.

Then you can either study the feature that breaks the access or decide not to use it.